# My Keynote version is still 6.5.3 even though mac app store says I installed 6.6.1

Tags: pages, keynote

I have a MacBook white late 2009, recently upgraded to 8 GB RAM and running on Yosemite 10.10.5. I updated Keynote and Pages to the newer versions. Mac app store says I was able to update to Keynote 6.6.1 and Pages 5.6.1. I restarted my laptop after the update. However, Keynote and Pages still insist that a newer version of the app is available. In effect, the new versions were not installed , but mac app store insists that they were installed. How can I solve this? thanks

Comment: I can confirm this problem.